# Android SQlite multithread access

Tags: android, database, multithreading, android-sqlite

I am using SQLiteOpenHelper to write and read from SQlite database on Android. When user clicks on UI I read from SQLite database using AsyncTask but at the exact samo moment I am updating and writing to the database in the background using other AsyncTask.

Every x times I get database locked exception. How can I fix this? Can SQlite be accessed somehow from multiple thread at the same time?

I am using it like that: I have a Database class which extends from SQLiteOpenHelper. I implemented onCreate and onUpgrade methods and everytime I am reading from database or writing to database I use SQLiteDatabase like that:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = null;
try {

    database = new Database(context).getWritableDatabase();

    ....
    writing and reading from database...
    ....

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
}
```

At the end I also close SQLiteStatements and Cursors if I use them. Should I use @Justin answer and have a singleton of database class in Application?

This is the error I get:

```
E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17377): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.skulptur/databases/LGM.s3db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377): Failed to open the database. closing it.
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:983)
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at   android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:750)
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
E/SQLiteDatabase(17377):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
```

Comment: I think everything you can do with android libraries on sqllite is synchronized.  Can't you just try and catch the exception and try again if you get the lock status?

Comment: Can you edit your post and give the first couple of lines of the exception and any cause statements?  I suspect this is less about what you are doing and more about re-using a closed database or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I do to avoid locking issues.. I let my application handle a single instance of my db helper and always refer to it to get a handle on my DB.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    // My instance of SQLiteOpenHelper
    public static DbHelper openHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (openHelper == null) {
            openHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        }
    }

    public synchronized static SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
        return openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Once you do this, anytime you want to do a db query, get the db handle like MyApp.getDB() and you will never have a locking issue.  Be sure to NEVER close the DB though.  This pattern maintains a single connection at all times in your app.  SQLite is meant to be synchronous on Android so if you have long running DB processes, like a 1000 inserts in a single transaction you'll want to code it like this:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for (DBRow row : insertList) {
        // your insert code
        insertRow(row);
        db.yieldIfContendedSafely();
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

This will allow other queries to interject themselves so that you won't see your app grind to a halt during background updates.

Comment: you can make your `SQLiteOpenHelper` a singleton better than overriding the `Application` class.

Comment: yep, I realized that after writing this :-\.. didn't feel like changing my answer

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong about your assumption of never having a locking issue: The only thing you are synchronizing is your access to the `getWritableDatabase` method, meaning: only *this* will never get called simultaneously, what ever happens with the `SQLiteDatabase` object it returns, is *not synchronized*.

Answer (score 3):

Implement a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) on top of the Database with [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) it will handle the threading.
You can consult this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to try.
First try passing the same instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to every of your tasks.
Second is using beginTransaction and endTransaction on your SQLiteDatabase inside of your Helper.
Third is adding `synchronized` to every of your helper methonds being used in tasks.

Comment: your way is fine, but I prefer ContentProvider, it gives me separation between app and db. You can also consider ORMLite or another ORM-like lib, there are many of them, good example is CROM what I did some time ago https://github.com/rysiekblah/crom

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using database connections incorrectly. It can be caused by unclosed  cursors or smth else. Sqlite database implementation is thread safe and can be accessed simultaneousely from different threads.
Please provide more details about your problem (exception stack trace, code sample that causes exception etc) in order we can help you.

Comment: How can you access SQLite db from different thread apart from main UI? I read few times that it can not be done.